Count Red Cells In Userform Display
I have a UserForm that displays and verifies data. If the data is not accurate the forecolor will turn red.
Because there is so much data to verify I would like a textbox on the first page that will display a count of UserForm textboxes that contain red font.
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim totalred As Integer
Dim ctrl As Control
totalred = 0
For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        ctrl.DisplayFormat.ForeColor.COLOR = vbRed
        totalred = totalred + 1
        UserForm1.INCORRECTCOUNT.Value = totalred
    End If
Next ctrl

End Sub

This does not show anything in the textbox. I had set up a MsgBox display which would only come up as zero.

I modified your code like this:
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
   Dim totalred As Integer
   Dim ctrl As Control
   
   totalred = 0
   
   For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
      If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
         If ctrl.ForeColor = vbRed Then
            totalred = totalred + 1
         End If
      End If
   Next ctrl

   UserForm1.INCORRECTCOUNT.Value = totalred
End Sub

Notice that I am checking the TypeOf against MSForms.TextBox, that I changed how the ForeColor is checked, and that I moved updating the total outside the loop.
